# Haskell: Delete Facebook Post using the "fb" package

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, haskell

I am trying to delete a Facebook post, using deleteObject from the [fb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fb-1.0.4/docs/Facebook.html) package.

My following approach actually deletes the post:

```
delete :: String -> IO ()
delete fbid = withManager $ \mgr -> FB.runFacebookT credentials mgr $ do
  del <- FB.deleteObject (T.pack fbid) [] userToken
  liftIO $ print (del :: Bool)
```

Unfortunately the result value does not get parsed properly but throws the following exception:

`*** Exception: ParseError {errorContexts = [], errorMessage = "Failed reading: satisfy", errorPosition = 1:1}`

The actual result from the Facebook-API is just `true`.

Any ideas on how to prevent this? Or maybe any other way to detect wether the request worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me that it's a bug in the `fb` package. The `deleteObject` function is implemented as

```
deleteObject = methodObject HT.methodDelete

methodObject method path query token =
  runResourceInFb $ do
    req <- fbreq path (Just token) query
    asJson =<< fbhttp req { H.method = method }

asJson = lift . asJsonHelper

asJsonHelper response = do
  val <- H.responseBody response C.$$+- C.sinkParser A.json'
  case A.fromJSON val of
    A.Success r -> return r
    A.Error str ->
        E.throw $ FbLibraryException $ T.concat
             [ "Facebook.Base.asJson: could not parse "
             , " Facebook's response as a JSON value ("
             , T.pack str, ")" ]
```

The `A.json'` is aeson's parser for JSON values, but as the [function's documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/latest/doc/html/Data-Aeson-Parser.html#v:json) states:

> Parse a top-level JSON value. This must be either an object or an array, per RFC 4627.

This behavior can be verified in GHCi:

```
Prelude Data.Attoparsec Data.Aeson> parse json' "true"
Fail "true" [] "Failed reading: satisfyElem"
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Nevertheless the exception is the same if you use `Bool`. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok. If I'm reading the source right, it looks like a bug in the `fb` package.